# Where to find a list of Google search operators?

Tags: google-search, search-engine, keyword, search-operators

I heard once that there are some search keywords or operators that google could use to enhance the search results. One of them was "NEAR"...

Say if I search

```
"make" NEAR "great again"
```

it would search pages with "*America*" or (more recently "*France*":), but not the pages entited "*Make Cookies*" and where there is a comment in the bottom of the page "*great again to see you, Steve!*"

My question is how to know if that keyword is or is not used.
Maybe it was removed, because it doesn't seem to work actually.
Is there anywhere a more or less official list of Google search help keywords?

Comment: Do you mean this one: [Refine web searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?visit_id=636778841915392259-3947781784&p=adv_operators&hl=en&rd=1)

Comment: @pritaeas The above link no longer list all the search operators.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Search Operators: The Complete List (42 Advanced Operators)](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/)
gives descriptions of the following 42 operators:

| Operator | Example |
| --- | --- |
| “search term” | “steve jobs” |
| OR | jobs OR gates / jobs |
| AND | jobs AND gates |
| - | jobs ‑apple |
| * | steve * apple |
| ( ) | (ipad OR iphone) apple |
| $ | ipad $329 |
| define: | define:entrepreneur |
| cache: | cache:apple.com |
| filetype: | apple filetype:pdf / apple ext:pdf |
| site: | site:apple.com |
| related: | related:apple.com |
| intitle: | intitle:apple |
| allintitle: | allintitle:apple iphone |
| inurl: | inurl:apple |
| allinurl: | allinurl:apple iphone |
| intext: | intext:apple |
| allintext: | allintext:apple iphone |
| AROUND(X) | apple AROUND(4) iphone |
| weather: | weather:san francisco |
| stocks: | stocks:aapl |
| map: | map:silicon valley |
| movie: | movie:steve jobs |
| in | $329 in GBP |
| source: | apple source:the_verge |
| _ | apple CEO _ jobs |
| info: / id: | info:apple.com / id:apple.com |
|  |  |
| #..# | wwdc video 2010..2014 |
| inanchor: | inanchor:apple iphone |
| allinanchor: | allinanchor:apple iphone |
| blogurl: | blogurl:microsoft.com |
| loc:placename | loc:”san francisco” apple |
| location: | loc:”san francisco” apple |
|  |  |
| + | jobs +apple |
| ~ | ~apple |
| inpostauthor: | inpostauthor:”steve jobs” |
| allinpostauthor: | allinpostauthor:steve jobs |
| inposttitle: | intitle:apple iphone |
| link: | link:apple.com |
| daterange: | daterange:11278–13278 |
| phonebook: | phonebook:tim cook |
| # | #apple |

Those near the end are no longer supported.

Something like `"make" AROUND(3) "great again"` is what you were originally looking for.

Comment: According to https://www.spyfu.com/blog/google-search-operators/ the following search operators are deprecated: `+`, `~`, `inpostauthor:`, `allinpostauthor:`, `inposttitle:`, `info:`, `daterange:`, `phonebook:`, `#`, `blogurl:`, `inanchor:`, `allinanchor:`, `loc:placename`, `location:`

Answer (score 1):

[Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch) has been used to list the search operators at https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433. As of October 12, 2023, the page title is "Refine Google searches"; unfortunately, regarding punctuation, symbols and search operators, it only mentions `site:` and `-`. Another source is Google Search Central.

- [Overview of search operators](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/search-operators).
  This article includes a table for the search operators, a link to the specific article and a brief description. The only search operator not having a link is:

  - `filetype:`.
- [site: search operator](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/search-operators/all-search-site)

  - `site:`.
- [cache: search operator](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/search-operators/web-search-cache)

  - `cache:`.
- [Google Images search operators](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/search-operators/image-search)

  - `src:`.
  - `imagesize:`.

It's worth mentioning that Google has transitioned from a keyword-based search engine to one that supports natural language queries while still allowing the use of some search operators.

It includes embedded tools like a currency converter, translator, dictionary, and calculator, among others and provides knowledge boxes.

Recently, they launched Google Bard, their response to OpenAI ChatGPT and the hype around Artificial Intelligence / Large Language Model-based tools.

The above makes the craft of search queries based on keywords and search operators to be "old school". It might be time to switch to a "prompt engineering" mindset. This doesn't mean that search operators have disappeared, it's just that Google continually looks to make its search engine to be the most used one. Niche needs might have to look to specialized offerings that might have a different business model.

## Punctuation, Symbols and Operators

According to https://www.spyfu.com/blog/google-search-operators/ the following search operators are deprecated: `+`, `~`, `inpostauthor:`, `allinpostauthor:`, `inposttitle:`, `info:`, `daterange:`, `phonebook:`, `#`, `blogurl:`, `inanchor:`, `allinanchor:`, `loc:placename`, `location:`. Below I will discuss some of them, adding, when possible, references to official docs or quotes from authoritative sources, like [Dan Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_M._Russell), [Matt Cutts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Cutts), [John Mueller](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/authors/john-mueller).

### `+` (plus) symbol

The `+` has suffered several changes. It was used to `force` results to include the term preceded with this symbol; later, it was used concerning Google+ pages. Currently, it's no longer supported as a search operator.

#### Related

- [Forced words in Google search query are being ignored, plus no longer working as explicit inclusion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19465/88163)

### `-`(dash / minus) symbol

Exclude items containing the term.

Usage `[term a] -[term b]`.

### `~` (tilde) and `*` (asterisk) symbols

These operators were retired.

The official confirmation of the deprecation of the `~` (tilde) operator is attributed to Dan Rusell in 2013.

I have not found official confirmation of the retirement of `*` (asterisk), but it's no longer included in official docs.

#### Related

- [Wildcards in Google advanced search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/99496/88163)

### `"` (double quote) symbol

Search the term, phrase or sentence as it was entered.

Usage `"[term or phrase or sentence]"`.

Alternative: On the Tools menu, select Verbatim

#### Related

- [How do I force Google Search to use the word I type with no "corrections"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/19658/88163)

### `filetype:` operator

Usage `filetype:[file type or file externsion]`.

Example `filetype:pdf`.

### <s>`related:` operator</s>

`related:` is no longer supported. Ref. Google Search Central Release Notes, [July 2023](https://developers.google.com/search/updates#july-2023):

> July 18: Removed the `related:` operator from the [search operators documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/search-operators), as it's no longer supported.

#### Reference

- [File types indexable by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/indexable-file-types)

## Keywords

Some keywords have the effect of making Google Search results show a special box. Some of these boxes are interactive.

| Tool | Usage | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Books | `book about [topic]` `what to read` | [Find books on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/11459602?hl=en) |
| Business Facts | `[business name]` | {2} |
| Calculator / Math | Arithmetic: `+` (addition), `*` (multiplication), `-` (subtraction), `/` (division), `^` (power) Trigonometrics: `sine([number])`, `cosine([number])`, etc. | {1} |
| Color Picker | `color picker` | {1} |
| Currency Converter | `[number] [currency] to [currency]` |  |
| Current Time | `time` `time [location]` |  |
| Competition Result/Score | `[competition name]` `[competitor a] vs [competitor b]` `[team a] vs [team b]` |  |
| Dictionary | `define [term]` | From [Learn about Dictionary boxes on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/10106608?hl=en) > Tip: You’re likely to get a Dictionary result when you start your search with “Define” or “What’s the meaning of." |
| Directions | `directions from [place A] to [place B]` `directions from [place A] near me` |  |
| Grammar and Spelling | `[query] grammar check` | [Learn about grammar check in Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13420782?hl=en) |
| Location Facts | `[location name]` `[address]` `[zip code]` `[region, country, city, landmark]` `[place type] near me` | {2} |
| People Facts | `[people name]` | {2} |
| Plot Function and Equations (Graph) | Function and variable as parameter i.e. `cos(x)` | {1} |
| Pronunciation | `pronounce [term]` |  |
| Recipes | `[recipe name]` `[dish name] recipe` |  |
| Shopping | `[product category]` | [Manage shopping preferences on Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/13005558?hl=en) |
| Stock Price | `price [stock ticker]` |  |
| Timer/Stopwatch | `timer` `timer [number] [time units]` `stopwatch` |  |
| Translate | `translate [term] to [language]` `[term] in [language]` |  |
| Travel from Gmail | `my reservations` `my flights` `my car reservation` `bus tickets` `my train tickets.` | [Get travel search results from Gmail](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1710607?hl=en) |
| Units Converter | `[number] [units] to [units]` | {1} |
| Video (TV, Movies) | `what to watch` | [Search for TV shows & movies on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9250033?hl=en) |
| Weather Forecast | `weather` `weather [location]` |  |

##### Notes

- {1} [Manage calculator, unit converter & color codes](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3284611?hl=en).
- {2} [How Google's Knowledge Graph works](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/9787176?hl=en).

---

According to the Way Back Machine,

| Archive | Title | Puntuaction and Symbols | Search Operators |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [2013-12-01](https://web.archive.org/web/20131201031958/https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) | Punctuation and symbols in search | `+`, `@`, `&`, `%`, `$`, `#`, `-`, `_` | No search operator is mentioned |
| [2015-05-03](https://web.archive.org/web/20150503113254/https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en) | Seach Operators | `+`, `@`, `$`, `#`, `-`, `"`, `*`, `..`, | `site:`, `link:`, `related:`, `OR`, `info:`, `cache:` |
| [2017-02-15](https://web.archive.org/web/20170215143732/https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en). Instead of a table, use headings. | Refine web searches | `@`, `$`, `#`, `-`, `"`, `*`, `..`, | `site:`, `related:`, `OR`, `info:`, `cache:` |

## Related

- [Hidden features of Google Search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/753/88163)
- [Is there a list of all the mini-apps/ commands you can access through Google search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106041/88163)

Comment: is strange is so hard to find a thing of google that should be public and easy to find

Comment: https://moz.com/learn/seo/search-operators

Comment: @serge , the moz link has a lot of obsolete stuff, like the `relate:` operator, it also repeats several stuff already listed on the link of the previous answer. My focus on this answer is to use as sources the official docs. Regarding your previous comment, I used to participate in the Google Search Community in Spanish, I am Top Contributor / Product Expert (not sure if they changed my status to "alumni" as I haven't participated in the last 2-3 years.) During the time that I actively participated, I continually gave feedback about the Help Center and the canonical community posts.

Comment: Long story short, they invest more in what the people use most. My observation is that as only a few people use the docs, they assign a relatively small budget... so the docs managers should do the best that they can with the budget to keep the docs simple and low maintenance cost.

Comment: what bugdet do you need to list 10 operators and give an example? )

Comment: @serge You might want to send a proposal to Google to run their business :)